# IntelliJ IDEA / WebStorm find and replace feature doesn't show the number of the current (highlighted) occurrence from total found

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

** Not sure how to correctly formulate the problem / title - will appreciate editors help

See attached screen shot

[image: Screen shot describing the issue + the expected behavior]

The find (strings) in file feature not showing the match number when searching for string in the file.

I expect to see the highlighted occurrence of total found, when the search occurrence highlighted in the editor tab. Very simple and straight forward to me.

May be I am missing something and it is configurable somewhere in the settings, please help.

EG, in above screen shot:
should show "4 of 8 matches" but only showing "8 matches"

Comment: WebStorm indeed does not show this information, and this is not configurable. Why exactly do you need to see the number of the current match?

Comment: Well, why not ?

Comment: Why show something if it serves no purpose?

Comment: I don't understand your concern. If I asked this question and spent my time for it with screenshots and further details, doesn't it means that I highly interested in this feature? Why should I bother with further explanations? What is the definition of 'purpose' in this context? Can you explain? IMO the purpose for me is to be able to navigate better in the source code and be more productive. Is it also serves this purpose for any other user, probably not exactly...

Comment: When we make decisions on what features should and should not be implemented in JetBrains products, we try to understand the specific user scenarios in which those features are used. For example, any information shown on the screen is useful if the user can make decisions based on that information, and useless otherwise. Right now I can't think of any scenario where I would use the match number when doing a search or replace operation. It's possible that I'm missing something - that's why I'm asking you. You're welcome not to bother, but it won't change IDEA's functionality.

Comment: Again. I used to it from several other IDEs and it helps to be more productive. It doesn't necessarily mean that it should serve a specific scenario. But I do understand that you need proper specifications if you want to add a feature. Any way, if this is not configurable, then I'll leave it... Thanks for the feedback!